# Can I use a custom ContractResolver when serializing with Json.Net's JObject.FromObject method?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

If I use JsonConvert.SerializeObject to serialize an object, the way to specify a custom contract resolver is this:

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = MyContractResolver.Instance };
var serializedString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( myObject, Formatting.None, serializerSettings )
```

However, a part of our application uses this approach to serialize:

```
var serializedString = JObject.FromObject(myObject).ToString();
```

One method calls FromObject to create a JObject, then passes it to an interface that expects a JObject, which then calls the ToString method. Given that I have to support that interface, I need to pass a JObject, not a string. There is another API that is available in Json.Net:

```
public static JObject FromObject(
    Object o,
    JsonSerializer jsonSerializer
)
```

Is there a default JsonSerializer that I can use in this call but add in my custom contract resolver?

Comment: You can use `JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(serializerSettings)`

Comment: Thx. I will try. You would think after months using Json.Net I could figure this out...

Comment: @Evk Your suggestion works. Add it as an answer and I will upvote!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = MyContractResolver.Instance };
var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(serializerSettings);
var serializedString = JObject.FromObject(myObject, serializer).ToString();
```

`JsonSerializer.CreateDefault` will create serializer with default settings (`JsonConvert.DefaultSettings`) and then merge settings you provide into them.

If you don't need those default settings, use

```
JsonSerializer.Create(serializerSettings)
```

That will just create serializer with settings you provide (no merging with default).

Comment: A colleague suggested that I add methods named "ShouldSerializeXXX" for each property to my class. I ended up doing it that way. Didn't know about that feature! This approach, however, is essential if you are dealing with 3rd party classes that you cannot modify.